# animation becomes choppy or appears to not work when placed on top of LayerDrawable

Tags: android, animation, android-layout

I have a LayerDrawable that I am creating in code because I have to do some color filtering to individual components of the layered image.  On top of the layered image I have to ImageViews on top of one another and one is set to invisible.  When the visible ImageView is clicked it rotates to 90 and made invisible and the invisible ImageView is made visible and rotated from -90 to 0.

My issue is when I added the LayerDrawable which is made up of 8 pngs to the Activity the animation didn't work as well as before.  It got very choppy or didn't appear to rotate at all.

Does anyone have any ideas regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the best way but what I have ended up doing was compositing the image myself.  By drawing all 8 images onto one bitmap and applying that single bitmap to the ImageView I was able to get my animation to perform as I wanted.  Now when I want to update a section of the composited image I have to make the change to the constituent bitmap and apply that to my Image View.

```
    final BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( this.getResources(), this.houseMatrix[0][0], opt );

    final int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    final Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap( width, height, Config.ARGB_8888 );

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter( new PorterDuffColorFilter( this.houseMatrix[0][1], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY ) );
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas( result );
    canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, 0, 0, paint );
    bitmap.recycle();

    for ( int i = 1; i < 8; i++ ) {
        paint.setColorFilter( new PorterDuffColorFilter( this.houseMatrix[i][1], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY ) );
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( this.getResources(), this.houseMatrix[i][0], opt );
        canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, 0, 0, paint );
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    this.house.setImageBitmap( result );
```